# How to flash Samsung devices from a GNU/Linux host running on ARM architecture?

Tags: rom-flashing, linux, heimdall, arm-processors

To flash a Samsung Galaxy S (where do not have root access in the currently running OS, and with a stock recovery) with a new firmware (OS), I need to connect it with a USB cable to another computer and flash it from there.

There is a further problem if the other computer (which runs a GNU/Linux, Ubuntu) is ARM (it's a Toshiba AC100). So to flash a new OS onto the Samsung Galaxy S through the USB cable from the other computer, I'd need something like `heimdall` for ARM. It's not among the available [pre-built downloads for `heimdall`](https://github.com/Benjamin-Dobell/Heimdall/downloads). Perhaps, I will have to try to build it for ARM then...

Is obtaining heimdall for Linux on ARM possible?

Comment: Perhaps, it would more convenient to try to build a distro source package, so that I can `apt-get build-dep` required for the build of `heimdall` in my Ubuntu 12.04. I'll have also a look for source or compiled packages in https://launchpad.net/+search?field.text=heimdall . I've already found one at https://launchpad.net/~heimdall-packagers/+archive/heimdall/+packages . It's a pity that AFAIK builds for ARM are not provided for PPAs at Launchpad.

Comment: A packaging request for heimdall for Ubuntu: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+bug/1036869

Comment: I don't quite know the virtualization situation with ARM, but you might also want to explore if perhaps it's workable to install a lightweight Linux distro running Heimdall in a virtual machine.

Comment: @Lie Ryan: I'll have to learn how to "forward" USB devices from the hostsystem to the virtual system.

Answer (score 5):

ARM is currently not supported officially by heimdall.
You might have luck compiling it yourself:

https://github.com/Benjamin-Dobell/Heimdall/

My advice however:
Use a supported platform **once** (Win/Mac/Linux-x86/x64) and enjoy on-device updates from then on via ClockWorkMod recovery (CWM) or RomManager.

Reason: Heimdall is only needed to install a bootstrap CWM once. After that you use the regular CWM.

Here's the guide from cyanogenmod:
http://wiki.cyanogenmod.com/wiki/Samsung_Galaxy_S:_Full_Update_Guide

CyanogenMod releases for CM7/9/10 in various flavours (stable, release candidate, nightly build) can be found here (Galaxy S i9000):

http://get.cm/?device=galaxysmtd

Comment: Thanks! BTW, the link to the latest version of CyanogenMod (at least) at that "Guide" page is a misleading (outdated): it points to a page that suggests CyanogenMod 7.2, but there's already a CyanogenMod 9 stable release for Samsung Galaxy S; check it at get.cm/?device=galaxysmtd&type=stable . Don't know whether the "latest release" to ClockworkMod recovery really points to an uptodate latest release, or there's likewise a newer one.

Comment: Added download link

Answer (score -1):

Yep, you should be able to compile from source.

Here are the steps to install ClockworkMod with heimdall from GNU/Linux or Ubuntu or whatever (I tested it with Samsung Galaxy tab 2.0 7 P3110):
0. by following the steps below be prepared to lose your guarantee or brick your device. Also make backups of your personal data.
1. install Heimdall (and Heimdall-frontend) this software is a flash tool which copies firmware images to device's specific memory area. You can find several guides how to install this even from source. You don't need windows stuff such as odin or Kies or a fake software which contains the usb drivers because most probably the kerner drivers are preinstalled on your GNU / Linux OS.
dmesg
2. download the recovery image to your host computer from clockworkmod rommanager (I'm not allowed to post URL. This is www dot clockworkmod dot com slash rommanager). Find your device on the list and download some files from 3 columns. Currently there are 3 columns:
~ROMs / ClockworkMod : contains superuser.zip: copy to sim card or to device. This zip contains application which allows to execute android apps with root mode. It is not needed to backup/restore device partitions. superuser.zip can be installed in recovery mode. Default recovery of Samsung (stored in RECOVERY partition) does not install the zip due to error: signature verification failed. If you want to root your device you must install a custom recovery image. Backup of original firmware does not require this superuser hack.
~Download Recovery: this is a custom recovery partition: you can install zips or create backup or flash partitions. You can navigate between the menus with keys only - no touch : volume up and down and choose with power button. Copy this to your GNU/Linux host (this image will be written to device with Heimdall)
~Download Touch Recovery: this is a custom recovery image. You can navigate between the menus with keys or touch : volume up and down and choose with power button. Don't forget to scroll there are a lot of menuitems!

1. turn off the tablet (wait around 10 secs while screen goes black)
2. hold down the volume key which is next to the power button and hold down the power button. You may keep it pressed as long as you like: logo appears then device reboots. When logo appears release keys. Android system recovery <3e> loads. Choose wipe data/factory reset with volume then select with power button. Choose Yes -- delete all user data.
3. choose reboot system now and don't allow it to reboot: immediatelly hold down the power button and the volume key which is on the far side. Keep it pressed until warning appears. Connect tablet to GNU/Linux host with USB cable then press the volume button next to power button.
4. with root permission run command on GNU/Linux host and be prepared for executing next step immediately
   sudo heimdall flash --RECOVERY recovery-clockwork-touch-6.0.2.7-p3110.img
5. when it completes it restarts the device: remove the cable and immediatelly boot into recovery mode: hold down the volume key which is next to the power button and hold down the power button: keep it pressed until logo is displayed on 2nd time then release them.
6. ClockworkMod Recovery loads... scroll down to see all the menuitems. You can create backup with "backup and restore" menu then "backup to external sdcard"
7. After all use last menuitem: +++Go Back+++ / reboot system now. "ROM may flash stock recovery on boot. Fix? : If you choose No then you can do the procedure again... / If you choose Yes then Samsung's recovery firmware gets overwritten by ClockworkMod Recovery.

Comment: What was your host computer? Was it ARM machine? If no, this is not an answer to the quesyion at all. If yes could you please share your experience of compilong heimdall onARM and perhaps the resulting packages.